# Spring boot hibernate always drop and create index on server startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Spring boot hibernate always drop and create ALL the indexs on server startup

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

Hibernate: alter table product_category_1 drop index UKkqfeccp86g07ipixmg25dnfia

Hibernate: alter table product_category_1 add constraint
UKkqfeccp86g07ipixmg25dnfia unique (org_id, pr_ty_id, name)

Hibernate: alter table product_category_2 drop index UKqa7n4ip0gfa4qpg034ba7bkob

Hibernate: alter table product_category_2 add constraint UKqa7n4ip0gfa4qpg034ba7bkob unique (org_id, pr_ca1_id, name)

Answer (score 0):

If your column type is a `longtext`, the index is not created so hibernate tries to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing, where starting my application resulted in my unique constraints being dropped and re-added:

```
Hibernate: alter table category drop constraint if exists UK_CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME
Hibernate: alter table category add constraint UK_CATEGORY_PARENT_NAME unique (parent_id, name)
```

After much internet digging and debugging, I found simply adding the following to my application properties no longer caused the constraints to be dropped:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.schema_update.unique_constraint_strategy=RECREATE_QUIETLY`

Answer (score 0):

As i observe that few of the unique key drop and create again and again with the property
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

You have to change the uniqueConstraints write inside the @Table annotation and put the uniqness check at column level

**Execute the drop and create unique index again and again every time you restart the project**

```
@Table(name = "XXXX", 
uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "tempUserId"}) },
)
```

**Resolve by adding the unique=true and column level**

```
@Column(unique = true)
private Long tempUserId;
```

And delete uniqueConstraints from the @Table annotation

This will resolve the problem